# highlight word under the cursor, except the one under the cursor

Tags: vim

I have an `autocmd` triggered by `CursorMoved` that will `match` same words as the one under the cursor as a syntax rule that simply inverts the foreground/background.

I use it to find all words equal to the one under the cursor for an instant typo check. Here it is:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * exe printf('match lCursor /\V\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
```

How can I exclude the current line from the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid any matches on the current line, you can use the `:help /\%l` special atom to match the current line number, and then assert a non-match via *negative lookahead*:

```
exe printf('match lCursor /\V\%%%dl\@!\<%s\>/', line('.'), escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
```

But in your answer you also indicate that the *current word* (not the entire line) should not be highlighted. This can be achieved again by negative lookahead, asserting that the cursor (`\%#`) is not inside the current keyword (`\<\k*...\k*\>`) *and* (`\&`) also matching the current word:

```
exe printf('match lCursor /\V\%%(\<\k\*\%%#\k\*\>\)\@!\&\<%s\>/', escape(expand('<cword>'), '/\'))
```